# Leave only unique elements in every dictionary value

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a dictionary with this structure

```
dict = {
    A : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    B : [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    C : [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    }
```

I want to end up with only the respective unique elements in each dictionary value

```
dict = {
    A : [1],
    B : [],
    C : [7]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a couple of comprehensions:

```py
d = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'B': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'C': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
}

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(x for lst in d.values() for x in lst)
result = {k: [x for x in lst if counts[x] == 1] for k, lst in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each key, if a value is in one of the other keys as well, remove it (or don't include it).

```py
def unique(val):
    count = 0
    for _, arr in pairs.items():
        for v in arr:
            if v == val:
                count = count + 1
    return count == 1

pairs = {
    'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'B' : [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'C' : [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
}
result = {}
for key, arr in pairs.items():
    result[key] = []
    for val in arr:
        if unique(val):
            result[key].append(val)
print(result) # {'A': [1], 'B': [], 'C': [7]}
```